# Escape in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to escape single and double quotes and some other characters in JavaScript

String to escape is **`dynamic initializer for 'Graphics::CDeviceCMYK::s_WicFactoryBoundData''**

I want to pass this as argument to some function.

I tried encodeURI(string);

Its not working. What's the correct way to do this ??

Comment: Nope, I don't think it is a duplicate. He is asking how to declare this particular string in js source file. Not how to encode it. Cerbrus has provided the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use double quotes (`"`) to declare the string::

```
var str = "`dynamic initializer for 'Graphics::CDeviceCMYK::s_WicFactoryBoundData''"
```